# How do you convert the Monero blockchain from Linux to Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, blockchain-import, blockchain-export

I know there is a tool that can be used to convert the format but what steps should be taken to do so?

Comment: I thought it was the same format and it would be enough to copy the db folder and point to it when starting the daemon from either system, not sure though

Comment: There's a blockchain_export and blockchain_import tool, and I've never been able to use my windows downloaded blockchain with my linux downloaded blockchain, so I'm fairly certain they are stored differently according to the os.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the current blockchain is compatible across different operating system as long as they have the same "amount of bits", i.e., 64 bit to 64 bit systems or 32 bit to 32 bit systems would work, but 32 bit to 64 bit systems wouldn't work.

If this doesn't work there is a second option. That is, you can export on your Linux system using the `blockchain_export` tool. This will create a blockchain.raw file, which you can subsequently import on Windows with the `blockchain_import` tool. Given that you use your own blockchain, you could do this with the `--verify 0` flag (this skips verification) to improve speed.

There are more specific instructions [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases) under "Updating: Blockchain Conversion".

Comment: Maybe that is were I'm coming unstuck, I've tried moving a windows x64 Monero blockchain via external hdd to a virtualbox Ubuntu i386 but the newest version simply failed to read it. It' could've been incompatible monero versions, but I considered it unlikely, the windows version was 9.3 x64 and the linux version was freshly compiled from the main repo as i386. In the end I had to give up and just downloaded it from scratch (which took forever but it worked).

Answer (score 2):

The current LMDB blockchain is compatible across operating systems. Just copy the files and use them directly. The new one in 0.10 is also compatible across 32/64 bit architectures. That is, the format is identical across ARM32/ARM64/x86/x86_64/Windows/Linux/Android/iOS/etc. There is nothing to convert.